# own list pop_back() also removes value in list of lists

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I'm newbie in programming so I'm learning c++ containers.

When I pop an element from a list, which I pushed into a list of lists before, the last element of pushed list is just garbage.
How to push just a copy of element with another memory allocation?

Here`s my push and pop back implementation:

```
void push_back(const T& data) {
        if (head == nullptr) {
            head = new Node;
            head->data = data;
            head->pPrev = nullptr;
            head->pNext = nullptr;
            tale = head;

        }
        else {
            Node* newNode = new Node;
            newNode->data = data;
            newNode->pPrev = tale;
            newNode->pNext = nullptr;
            tale->pNext = newNode;
            tale = newNode;
            //delete newNode;
        }
        Size++;
    }
T& pop_back() {
        if (Size == 1) {
            Size = 0;
            T x = head->data;
            delete head;
            head = tale = nullptr;
            return x;
        }
        else {
            Node* tempo = tale;
            T x = tempo->data;
            tale = tempo->pPrev;
            tale->pNext = nullptr;
            delete tempo;
            Size--;
            return x;
        }
    }
```

For example, consider the following sequence:

- push into list of lists [1,2,3] -> list of lists contains [[1,2,3]]
- pop one element from the list -> list is [1,2]
- then push 4 -> list is [1,2,4]
- push into list of lists -> list of lists is [[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]
- pop element from list -> list is [1,2]
- but(!) the list of lists is now [[1,2,3],[1,2,-572662307]]

Comment: My educated guess is, your list class doesn't implement copying correctly, which bites you when the list of lists does `head->data = data;` where `data` is itself of type `list`. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve]

Comment: `pop_back()` returns a reference to a local variable. That variable is destroyed when the function exits, leaving the caller with a dangling reference. Any attempt by the caller to actually use the returned value would exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i`ll try to write deep copying for operator=

Comment: It is hard to write a safe pop function that both returns the popped value and removes the popped value. The C++ Standard Library doesn't even try. It splits the operations up into `top` to get the value and `pop` to remove it.

Comment: @user4581301 What is it that makes it hard to return the popped value and remove it at the same time safely? I made a [little test](https://godbolt.org/z/evfesvovT) but I can't figure out where it could go wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Exception safety. If the object throws an exception when it's copied, moved or otherwise transfers ownership to the caller, the container has been modified and the instance is lost. You can work around the problem, but the results usually aren't as elegant as just splitting the two jobs up. Could be other reasons, but the exception hole is the one that stands out.

Comment: @user4581301 I see what you mean. If one doesn't want to work around that problem, only accepting types that are `is_nothrow_move_constructible` could be the easy way out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yeah. There's no fear if you've got a stack of `int`. So modifying my earlier statement, it should read *It is hard to write a safe pop function for a generic container...*